# How to set GraphicsDevice.GraphicsProfile

Tags: windows, xna, xamarin.android, monogame

In a classic XNA application this value is set through the application properties.

By default this value is set to `HiDef`, at least on the machine I am currently using. But it has to be set to `Reach` to run.

My problem is that I did not find any way to effectively change this value using monogame. The property window is obviously not the same as with XNA and I did not find any config values.

Changing the value in the code, in the `Game` constructor or the `LoadContent` method does not solve my problem.

---

PS: My original problem, which I think is caused by this `GraphicsDevice.GraphicsProfile`, is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900957/monogame-draw2d-sample-accessviolation-exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In constructor metod, create new event handler for your GraphicsDeviceManager:

```
graphics.PreparingDeviceSettings += new EventHandler<PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs (graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings);
```

(default handler is created by doubletapping Tab after +=)

then in event handler add folowing code

```
void graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings(object sender, PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs e)
{
e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.GraphicsProfile = GraphicsProfile.Reach;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good but... I am trying to find why my `PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs` object does not have any GraphicsProfile property. Just `Adapter, DeviceType, PresentationParameters`.

Comment: I don't understand how two implementation of the same class are present in `MonoGame.Microsoft.Xna.Framework` and `MonoGame.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics`. The one in `...Framework` is the one used by `PreparingDeviceSettingEventArgs` but the other one contains the property `GraphicsProfile`.
https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/GraphicsDeviceInformation.cs
https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/GraphicsDeviceInformation.cs  
(I feel like I am missing something very stupid here...)

Comment: I guess you gave me the answer. My code is still not running but I think this is another problem now. So my story continue on [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929628/how-to-change-graphicsprofile) now.