# How to access PreparingDeviceSettingEventArgs.GraphicsDeviceInformation.GraphicsProfile?

Tags: xamarin.android, monogame

I would like to change the `GraphicsProfile` to `Reach`. As told to me [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903016/how-to-set-graphicsdevice-graphicsprofile) the solution would be to use:

```
graphics.PreparingDeviceSettings += (s, e) =>
{
    e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.GraphicsProfile = GraphicsProfile.Reach;
};
```

But my `e.GraphicsDeviceInformation` does not contain the `GraphicsProfile`property.

I don't understand how two implementations of the same class are present in [MonoGame.Microsoft.Xna.Framework](https://raw.github.com/mono/MonoGame/develop/MonoGame.Framework/GraphicsDeviceInformation.cs) and [MonoGame.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics](https://raw.github.com/mono/MonoGame/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/GraphicsDeviceInformation.cs).
The one in `...Framework` is the one used by `PreparingDeviceSettingEventArgs` but the other one contains the property I need: `GraphicsProfile`.

(I feel like I am missing something very stupid here...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not supported. Simply create an XNA project for PCs.

But I then wonder how I could do if I want to support an Android build (MonoGame) which would not fit with the [*High* profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604995.aspx).